# Parsing text from certain "html elements" using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

What I've seen so far is that the page source of a webpage if filtered by selenium then it is possible to parse text or something necessary from that page source applying bs4 or lxml no matter the page source was javascript enabled or not. However, my question is how can I parse documents from a certain `html elements` by filtering selenium and then using bs4 or lxml library. if the below pasted element is considered then applying bs4 or lxml the way i move is:

```
html='''
<tr onmouseover="this.originalstyle=this.style.backgroundColor;this.style.backgroundColor='DodgerBlue';
this.originalcolor=this.style.color;this.style.color='White';Tip('<span Style=Color:Red>License: <BR />20-214767 (Validity: 21/05/2022)<BR />20C-214769 (Validity: 21/05/2022)<BR />21-214768 (Validity: 21/05/2022)</span>');" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor=this.originalstyle;this.style.color=this.originalcolor;UnTip();" style="background-color:White;font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:12px;">
        <td style="font-size:10px;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;" align="left">AAYUSH PHARMA</td><td style="font-size:10px;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;" align="left">PUNE-1ST FLOOR, SR.NO.742/A, DINSHOW APARTMENT,,SWAYAM HOSPITAL AND NURSING HOME, BHAWANI PETH</td><td style="font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;" align="center">RH - 3</td><td>swapnil ramakant pawar, BPH, [140514-21/04/2017]</td>
</tr>
'''
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
#rest of the code here

from lxml.html import fromstring
tree = fromstring(html)           
#rest of the code here
```

Now, how can I filter the above paste `html` portion using selenium and then apply bs4 library on it? Could not think of `driver.page_source` as it is only applicable when filtered from a webpage.

To be a little more specific, if I want to use something like below, then how can it be?

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

element_html = driver-------(html)  #this "html" is the above pasted one
print(element_html)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`driver.page_source` would give you the complete HTML source code of the page at one particular moment. You, though, having an element instance, can get to it's `outerHTML` using `.get_attribute()` method:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("some_id")
element_html = element.get_attribute("outerHTML")

soup = BeautifulSoup(element_html, "lxml")
```

As far as extracting the `span` element source from out of the `mouseover` attribute - I would first parse the `tr` element with `BeautifulSoup`, get the `onmouseover` attribute and then use a regular expression to extract the html value from inside the `Tip()` function call. And then, re-parse the span html with `BeautifulSoup`:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<tr onmouseover="this.originalstyle=this.style.backgroundColor;this.style.backgroundColor='DodgerBlue';
this.originalcolor=this.style.color;this.style.color='White';Tip('<span Style=Color:Red>License: <BR />20-214767 (Validity: 21/05/2022)<BR />20C-214769 (Validity: 21/05/2022)<BR />21-214768 (Validity: 21/05/2022)</span>');" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor=this.originalstyle;this.style.color=this.originalcolor;UnTip();" style="background-color:White;font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:12px;">
        <td style="font-size:10px;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;" align="left">AAYUSH PHARMA</td><td style="font-size:10px;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;" align="left">PUNE-1ST FLOOR, SR.NO.742/A, DINSHOW APARTMENT,,SWAYAM HOSPITAL AND NURSING HOME, BHAWANI PETH</td><td style="font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;" align="center">RH - 3</td><td>swapnil ramakant pawar, BPH, [140514-21/04/2017]</td>
</tr>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
mouse_over = soup.tr['onmouseover']

span = re.search(r"Tip\('(.*?)'\)", mouse_over).group(1)
span_soup = BeautifulSoup(span, "lxml")
print(span_soup.get_text())
```

Prints:

```
License: 20-214767 (Validity: 21/05/2022)20C-214769 (Validity: 21/05/2022)21-214768 (Validity: 21/05/2022)
```

Comment: You perhaps noticed that the `span` tag in the above pasted html elements are within javascript that is why i'm after such usage. Thanks again.

Comment: @Topto ah, now I see that it sits inside the `onmouseover` attribute. I'll provide a sample on how to extract it using bs4, give me one minute.

Comment: @Topto updated with a reproducible sample, hope this is what you're asking about. Thanks.

Comment: Sir, could you please provide me with any link tracking which I can reach someplace to learn regex.

Comment: @Topto I would probably start with the [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html). Then, practice and practice - it is a very generic and useful skill to have (even though overused sometimes :)).